# Using tidyverse to reshape a data.frame and its column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` of some experiment with several factors and measured values for each sample. For example:

```
factors <- c("age","sex")
```

The `data.frame` looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:10,function(i) expand.grid(age=c("Y","O"),sex=c("F","M")) %>% dplyr::mutate(val=rnorm(4))))
grouped.mean.val.df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by_(.dots=factors) %>% dplyr::summarise(mean.val=mean(val))
```

I want to create a `data.frame` which has a single row and the number of columns is the number of factor combinations (i.e. `nrow(expand.grid(age=c("Y","O"),sex=c("F","M"))` in this example), where the value is the `mean` `df$val` for the corresponding combination of `factors`.

To get the `mean` `df$val` for each combination of factors I do:

```
grouped.mean.val.df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by_(.dots=factors) %>% dplyr::summarise(mean.val=mean(val))
```

And the resulting `data.frame` I'd like to obtain is:

```
res.df <- data.frame(Y.F=grouped.mean.val.df$mean.val[1],
                     Y.M=grouped.mean.val.df$mean.val[2],
                     O.F=grouped.mean.val.df$mean.val[3],
                     O.M=grouped.mean.val.df$mean.val[4])
```

Is there a `tidyverse` way to get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `unite` and then a `spread`.  `unite` the 'age' and 'sex' to create a single column, `mutate` the values to `factor` (to make the order as the same as in the expected) and do a `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
grouped.mean.val.df %>%
   unite(agesex, age, sex, sep=".") %>% 
   mutate(agesex = factor(agesex, levels = unique(agesex))) %>%
   spread(agesex, mean.val)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#     Y.F   Y.M    O.F     O.M
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 0.0695 0.411 -0.118 0.00577
```

---

Also, instead of `group_by_`, we can use `group_by_at`which takes strings as variables

```
df %>%
     group_by_at(factors) %>%
     summarise(mean.val = mean(val)) %>%
     unite(agesex, age, sex, sep=".") %>% 
     mutate(agesex = factor(agesex, levels = unique(agesex))) %>%
     spread(agesex, mean.val)
```